# how to read a http video stream with libavcodec (ffmpeg)

Tags: iphone, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to read a real-time http video stream (I've set one up using VLC and my webcam) using libavcodec from ffmpeg.  so far I've been able to read an mpeg file fine but when I pass a url instead of the file name it hangs (I assume it's waiting for the end of the file).

anyone have experience/ideas on how to do this?  I'm also open to alternatives if people have other suggestions.

the end goal is to do live video-streaming on the iphone.  apple's http live streaming has too much lag for what I need but that's for another post :)

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

if you aren't using apple's way, you can't.

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit I dont quite understand what you want to achieve, however, based on my interpretation of the question it seems like it is related to the segmenting of the video.

The segmenting can be achieved using ffmpeg and libavcodec (look for example [here](http://urlgrey.net/?p=242), key line is the one with packet.flags). Just remember that the segment length (in time) depends on the keyframe interval (for h264 at least). If you want an example of a full segmented streaming solution that works (most of the time), check [here](https://github.com/carsonmcdonald/HTTP-Live-Video-Stream-Segmenter-and-Distributor).

Otherwise, you have to dig into the codec and create the transport stream manually. The MPEG2-TS, which is what iOS supports, can be a little bit difficult sometimes, but it is not too bad. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

you can use libcurl to download http segment file